# JQuery Datatable adding a row with mdata array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a datatable which gets its data over mData.

```
var processURL="path"
    $.ajax(
        {
        type        : "GET",
        url         : processURL,
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : "json",
        success     : function (d) 
            {       
            var oTable = $('#Testtable').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDestroy();
            //Tabelle zu Datentabelle
            $('#Testtable').dataTable(
                        {
                        bJQueryUI: true,
                        "sScrollY": "200px",
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "sDom": "frtiS",
                        "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "aaData": d.COMMENT,
                        "aoColumns":    
                            [
                            { "mData": "KOMMENTARTYP" },
                            { "mData": "a" },
                            { "mData": "b" },
                            { "mData": "c" },
                            { "mData": "d" },
                            { "mData": "e" },
                            { "mData": "f" }
                            ],
                        "aoColumnDefs": 
                            [ 
                                { 
                                "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 6 ]
                                } 
                            ]

                        }).makeEditable(
                            {
                            sUpdateURL: function(value, settings)
                                {
                                alert(CommentIDuebergabe);
                                alert(value);

                                return(value);
                                }
                            });

            var oTable1 = $('#Testtable').dataTable();
            oTable1.fnStandingRedraw();                   
            },              
        error : function (d) 
            {                       
            alert('error');
            }
        });
```

It works fine but if I add data with fnAddData like this:

```
function adddata()
    {
    $('#KommentareTabelle').dataTable().fnAddData(
            [
            "1. Spalte",
            "2. Spalte",
            "3. Spalte",
            "4. Spalte",
            "5. Spalte",
            "6. Spalte",
            "7. Spalte"  
            ])
    }
```

I get an error " unknown parameter'KOMMENTARTYP' in data source.

If I add data like this in a normal datatable without mdata it works.

Where is the Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: If you want to add data to a mdata Jquery Table you have to use the same array which you used in mdata:

```
function adddata() 
    {
    oTable = $('#KommentareTabelle').dataTable();
    oTable.fnAddData(
        [
            {
            "KOMMENTARTYP":        "Zeile 0", 
            "a":                   "Zeile 1",
            "b":                   "Zeile 2",
            "c":                   "Zeile 3",
            "d":                   "Zeile 4",
            "e" :                  "Zeile 5",
            "f" :                  "Zeile 6"
            }
        ]); 
    }
```